# Allow custom PHP user code in an existing tool, security issues and methods to block the use of some variables

Tags: php, security, variables

I want to extend an existing PHP tool which provides automatic CRUD forms for a Database. I want to introduce the possibility to add completely custom php pages (sort of feature extensions). I want to keep the solution as easy as possible, I was thinking about implementing the feature in the following way:

- the user-developer adds a new page from an admin menu, specifying the
  PHP source file name (e.g. myfile)
- the system automatically adds a menu item link for this new page
- the system, when a "custom php page" link is clicked, just loads the file (something like: requires './custom_files/'.$myfile.'.php')

What security issues can you see in this approach? The first issue to handle is the fact that the user-developer could use variable names which are used by the system itself, and this can of course lead to problems. In order to handle this aspect, I was thinking about forcing the user-developer to use specific variable names: once you have chosen a prefix, e.g. custom_vars, the user can just modify variables starting with that prefix, e.g. $custom_vars_a, $custom_vars_test, $_POST['custom_vars_test2'] and so on. In this way I will be sure to avoid conflict.

Is there any way to avoid the modification of variables whose names don't start with the specified string?

I know the solution is a bit hacky and not very elegant but I need an implementation very quickly.

Comment: Read my lips: I-M-P-O-S-S-I-B-L-E

Comment: Give Sun/Oracle a call. They know how to make secure VM's allowing untrusted applet code to be run securely. </sarcasm>
TL/DR: "Your Common Sense" nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not, the user can modify your vars - your problem is, the user can do nearly everything, if you allow him, to upload own php files and it's impossible to detect some malicious code.

What you can do is using `runkit`([link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php)) to load your file in an restricted area - means you have to set disallowed functions, restrict php ini, etc.

But why not simply create an generic crud page, which could handle different databases and could be modified by the user?

Comment: malicious code is not a problem, who adds the custom code is not the final user, the scenario is: there is an admin which uses the tool to provide an application to final users.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution would be to use [PHP Namespaces](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Assign a randomly generated `namespace` name to the user. The user is restricted to that namespace. That way you're sure to avoid naming conflicts. Please note that `namespaces` are a relatively new feature. `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)`

I can't begin to elaborate the security issues this presents, since the user can do anything you, the developer, can do. (shell access, configuration, file system access)

If you expect the users to be malicious *(user is always malicious)* there's no way to restrict them except maybe using `runkit` as previously suggested.

Comment: thanks for the hint, namespaces is maybe the right direction to take, but is it possible to define a namespace just for a PHP file which is then included in another (global, no namespace defined) main file? 

And what happens with $_POST, $_GET etc, e.g. if I submit a field whose name is "test" can I still find the value in $_POST['test']?

Finally, I need the user can access (read) the tool's variables (no namespace), but I don't want him to modify them, I think this cannot be realized using namespaces right?

Comment: About malicious users, no, only the admin can add a file...well it can be malicious code but it is his own application so why should he write malicious code? The final user can just USE the final application.

Comment: I am testing the use of namespace, it seems it works with constant, function and class names but not with variables: if test.php includes  a file test2.php having is own namespace and in test2.php you have $myvar = 'hello world', from test.php I can see the value assigned to $myvar in test2.php (echo $test shows 'hello world).